# Network segment gaps, when offset

Tags: coordinate-system, cartography

I'm having an issue when offsetting a line shapefile. For some reason when the lines are offset, ArcGIS isn't drawing some segments although the segments are there confirmed via “identify”. Has someone come across a similar problem? why is this happening and how does it get resolved?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it could be a simple drawing error.  Have you tried refreshing the view?  Does this fix it?  I know the drawing can be interrupted if you happen to press a button or click the mouse while the map is still being drawn, and a simple re-fresh fixes it.

Comment: Yeah, i have tried that. Even opening in another project and other computer and it is always the sames links that are not drawn. If i had more points i could post the picture that shows where is happening. I also tried to export those links to a new shapefile and when i offset them, they disappear again. I'm thinking there must be either something worn with the shapefile or ArcGis' bug